# Using PyQt and for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqt4

I am seeking to scrape links from a list of web pages with addresses in such a format that it is the most efficient to use a for loop (for n in range(1,N), as an example, and connect them with base url)

- example.com/page1
- example.com/page2
- example.com/page3

...

- example.com/page**N**

Because the contents are produced by Javascripts, I attempted to build simple Python web-scraper using **PyQt4** with templates provided [here](https://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/):

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()
```

**[update]**
I am able to use ekhumoro's method, but it is somewhat unstable when I code in this way:

```
import sys, signal, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import UnicodeDammit
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

    def process(self, items):
        self._items = iter(items)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            self._url, self._func = next(self._items)
            self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(self._url))
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        return True

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self._func(self._url, self.mainFrame().toHtml())
        if not self.fetchNext():
            print('# processing complete')
            QtGui.qApp.quit()

def funcA(url, html):
    print '# processing:', url
    soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(html), "lxml")
    newslinks = soup.select('dt a')
    if len(newslinks) == 0:
        print 'captured', len(newslinks), 'urls - this does not work'
    else:
        print 'captured', len(newslinks), 'urls'

url = "http://english.yonhapnews.co.kr/search1/2601000000.html?query=japan&page_no="
targets = []
failedtargets = []
futurelinks = []
newslinks = []

for n in range(1,30):
    newurl = url + str(n), funcA
    targets.append(newurl)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
webpage = WebPage()
webpage.process(targets)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Each round, I expect to collect ten addresses. When the iteration gets to 20, however, the program starts getting a lot of zeroes (showing "captured 0 urls - this does not work" on the terminal screen). But the occurrence of those zeroes seems to be in different places at different trials.

Comment: Why would you want to use code that you know doesn't work, when you have been provided with a solution which you know does work?

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer you provided in that earlier question! For me, that solution works well when you have two addresses to parse but gets a bit unwieldy when I will need to do it for dozens of pages.

I try to use one function (funcA) to do all the addresses within a list, but it appears to be a bit unstable (sometimes it returns result but sometimes not). So I am still looking for a better solution...

Comment: I tried it with the urls in your example, and it worked as expected. Maybe you're just not using it in the right way.

Comment: I am probably not using it in the right way... can you take one more look with the new codes I updated? 

It only gets unstable when I am going with a n bigger than 20. I am now primarily using **funcA** to do everything I want. My ultimate goal is to save **newslinks** to an external document for further processing.

Comment: IIt seems that webkit is unable to handle all the content on those pages - adverts, maybe? The actual script works fine, though. I ported it to PyQt5 and used [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) (which is chrome-based), and it processed all thirty pages without any problems.

Comment: Thanks and it is good to know! Do you mind sharing the codes? I have not come across similar solutions on this site before.